# How to display RGB data as image in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Opening an image file to display in a frame or button in tkinter is simple, but I have images stored in arrays as raw RGB data (for transmission over SPI to a small LCD display). I wish to show this data as a proper image (exactly as processed for the small lcd display) in a frame or button, with tkinter.

I need some steering in how to approach this. Cheers.

Comment: Depending on what you mean by *"in arrays as raw RGB data"*, you can use `PIL.Image.fromarray()` or `PIL.Image.frombuffer()` to make a PIL Image, then you can convert that to a Tk photo/image... https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.fromarray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your input. I 've been chewing on it for a bit, and now have working code for the task. It takes the image as has been manipulated by numpy or opencv, transforms it to tk format and then shows the original and reduced bitdepth images side by side, with pixel doubling. Here is the snippet with the relevant code:

```
def nextimg(self):
    f = self.image[self.ptr % self.length]
    self.drawImage(f)
    f = f[...,::-1]
    f = np.repeat(f,2,axis=0)
    f = np.repeat(f,2,axis=1)
    temp=self.size
    self.size=[480,480]
    if self.bpp == 12: g = self.imageConvert_tk12(f)
    elif self.bpp == 16: g = self.imageConvert_tk16(f)
    else: g = self.imageConvert_tk18(f)
    self.button_image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(np.uint8(f)).convert('RGB'))
    self.button_image2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(np.uint8(g)).convert('RGB'))
    self.button_pic1.configure(image=self.button_image1)
    self.button_pic2.configure(image=self.button_image2)
    self.ptr+=1
    self.size=temp

def imageConvert_tk18(self,image):
    x,y = image.shape[0:2]
    arr =np.ndarray((x,y,3))
    arr[...,:] = (np.uint8(image[...,:] >> 2) * 4)
    return arr

def imageConvert_tk16(self,image):
    x,y = image.shape[0:2]
    arr = np.ndarray((x,y,3))
    arr[...,0:3:2] = (np.uint8(image[...,0:3:2] >> 3) * 8)
    arr[...,1] = (np.uint8(image[...,1] >> 2) * 4)
    return arr

def imageConvert_tk12(self,image):
    x,y = image.shape[0:2]
    arr =np.ndarray((x,y,3))
    arr[...,:] = (np.uint8(image[...,:] >> 4) * 16)
    return arr
```

I also understand a lot more now about lists and arrays. Opencv creates an np.ndarray , which I now understand is a 1-dimensional array (or list in list?) but with a given  x-dimensional shape.

Of course I am hoping there might be another solution without having to resort to PIL as intermediary, but if not this will work fine.

Please feel free to suggest improvements to my code!

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your array rgb data into an Image object that tkinter knows.
For this the best approach is to convert your rgb data to a PIL Image.
Depending on how your rgb values are ordered in the array you might need to do some conversions: if rgb data are interleaved (usually the case) or in separate channels/plans, the conversion might fail.

Check for here for converting an array to a pil image.
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.fromarray

Once the conversion to Pil Image is done you can use it in tkinter.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import numpy as np
#convert array to PiL Image    
PIL_image = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(your_rgb_array)).convert('RGB')

tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(PIL_image )
label1 = tkinter.Label(image=tk_image )
```

For displaying the image you should have a look at tk.Canvas:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_canvas.htm

Comment: a PIL Image is a list of RGB-tuples, am I correct? The raw RGB data i have is stored in an array of shape (x,y,3).

Comment: Is there a way to do this with numpy, I wonder? I am trying to do this with a few external modules as possible. I am using opencv and numpy.

Comment: (x,y,3) shall be fine. Did you try? What do you call array? Is it a list of list of list?

Comment: I open all image files with cv2.imread, as far as I know it creates a numpy array (x,y3) and I processes them as such.

Comment: I am getting an error when trying to import ImageTk:
Importerror: cannot import name 'ImageTk' from 'PIL' but Image imports fine. Version is 8.1.2

Comment: It is possible you do not use the right PIL version (there are some fork). Try this one: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageTk.html#module-PIL.ImageTk

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html

Comment: Import problem solved but I am still having issues. Experimenting now, so will post results later.

Comment: You can check if opencv correctly read your image by doing: 
`cv2.imshow('image',img)` `cv2.waitKey(0)`. But if this works you can directly read the image file using PIL, no need to use opencv.

Comment: Yes, I am working on that. I am comparing the output of the image read functions of PIL, tkinter and opencv. cv.imread creates a 2D array with R,G,B triplets in a list, andt when sliced, it neatly reports single R, G, or B values. Still working on it, when I have figured this part out, I will report my findings.

Comment: The reason I am putting extra effort in to this is so that I can understand arrays and lists better. I am relatively new to this kind of operations and sometimes they can initially dumbfound me :)

Comment: If you read a jpg/png/... from a file using opencv, the cv ordering is BGR instead of RGB that is used by most of the other Images libs (eg PIL,). you can ask cv to convert back to RGB before slicing the underlying np arrays. (a opencv matrix is actually a np array)

Comment: Yes I am aware of this and the solution is also easy : [ : , : , -1]         :D
the whole reason I asked if it can be done with numpy is because the image is converted to an np array.

Comment: silly me, I meant [...,::-1] of course.